# Android s3 SDK: Upload Large Files fail using TransferManager class

Tags: android, amazon-s3, sax

We have a couple of Android apps that use S3 extensively. We are using TranferManager class from the Android SDK to upload files to S3. It says: "E/HttpClient( 6081): com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Couldn't initialize a sax driver for the XMLReader"

We have tried using both 0.1.0 and 0.2.1 versions of SDK and both are giving the same issue on large (200MB+) uploads.

Following is our code snippet:

```
ObjectMetadata attMetaData = new ObjectMetadata();
attMetaData.setContentLength(attachment.getFileSize());                                                                                             
TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(Utility.getInstance().getAWSInstance(OutboxService.this));
Transfer myUpload = tm.upload(Constants.S3.BUCKET, Attachment.mediaFolders.get(attachment.getFileType())+ attachment.getFileName(), is, attMetaData);
```

Exception log is:

```
W/HttpMethodBase( 6081): Going to buffer response body of large or unknown size. Using   getResponseBodyAsStream instead is recommended.
D/dalvikvm( 6081): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 10875 objects / 636320 bytes in 61ms
D/NativeCrypto( 6081): Freeing OpenSSL session
D/NativeCrypto( 6081): Freeing OpenSSL session
E/HttpClient( 6081): Unable to unmarshall response (Couldn't initialize a sax driver for the XMLReader): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
E/HttpClient( 6081): <InitiateMultipartUploadResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Bucket>ltd_avmessaging</Bucket><Key>videos/2498992-1313049697.3gp</Key>  <UploadId>Tv397TYchM_.U_JDE7PyQcF21lyrtQ7jZYoFG08PgRt07YPn6f_LxlRHVSneGxfdFkGktBs9bIBCA.hAdRb88g--</UploadId></InitiateMultipartUploadResult>
E/HttpClient( 6081): com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Couldn't initialize a sax driver for the XMLReader
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$InitiateMultipartUploadResultUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$InitiateMultipartUploadResultUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClient.handleResponse(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.MultipartUploadCallable.initiateMultipartUpload(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.MultipartUploadCallable.call(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.MultipartUploadCallable.call(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.TransferStateUpdatingCallable.call(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.TransferStateUpdatingCallable.call(Unknown Source)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
E/HttpClient( 6081):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
```

E/HttpClient( 6081):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    E/HttpClient( 6081):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    E/HttpClient( 6081):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can solve a lot of these SAX parser errors when using S3 by setting the following system property.

> System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver", "org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");

(Taken from https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=251760&#251760)